Is there a way to perform a Hierarchical Partitioning with NMDS in R?
I performed non-metric multidimensional scaling (NMDS) on my ecological data and I was satisfied with my results, but I was told that I should use hierarchical partitioning in my analysis to check for individual variable contributions because this method accounts for possible autocorrelation in ecological variables. I ended up using rdacca.hp package in R and it seemed to do what I needed. I am hesitant on my results and what to do next after performing rdacca.hp.
What I did was rdacca.hp of full dataset which is over three years (2021-2023). I knew year is important, so I performed rdacca.hp again for each year of data as well. I am getting generally different results in the complete data rdacca.hp results compared to what my NMDS had indicted were important variables. This led me to be unsure of what I was doing and whether I was at all doing the right thing.
I do not have a statistician that I can consult with, so I am wondering if somebody could either give me some advice on whether what I am doing is correct or suggest alternatives.
RDCCA 2021-2023 data:
# Method_Type: "CCA"   "adjR2"
# Total_explained_variation: 0.066 (6.6%)

variable    Unique  Average.share   Individual  I.perc(%)
jcollect    0.0042  0.0221  0.0263  39.85
time.collect    -0.0018 0.0023  0.0005  0.76
time.collr  0.0008  0.0019  0.0027  4.09
am.pm   0.0012  -0.0007 0.0005  0.76
dbh.cm  0.0038  -0.0026 0.0012  1.82
aspect  -0.0076 0.0009  -0.0067 -10.15
yr  -0.0028 0.0043  0.0015  2.27
wk  -0.0001 0.0034  0.0033  5
month   0.0006  0.0033  0.0039  5.91
temp.collect    0.0025  -0.0013 0.0012  1.82
year.jcollect   0.0029  0.0259  0.0288  43.64
humidity_imputed    -0.0055 0.0047  -0.0008 -1.21
wk.yr   -0.0008 0.0047  0.0039  5.91

Output of NMDS on cleaned site-level (2021-2023) data after removal of some rare influential species:
***VECTORS                  
                    
    NMDS1   NMDS2   r2  Pr(>r)  
dbh.cm  -0.32437    0.94593 0.026   0.059   .
temp.collect    0.35088 -0.93642    0.0249  0.0664  .
humidity_imputed    -0.69403    0.71995 0.0388  0.0143  *
---                 
Signif.codes:0‘***’0.001‘**’0.01‘*’0.05‘.’0.1‘’1            
Permutation: free                   
Number of permutations: 9999                
---------------                 
Goodness of fit:                    
    r2  Pr(>r)          
jcollect    0.398   0.0479  *       
time.collect    0.0654  0.0866  .       
time.collr  0.0186  0.095   .       
am.pm   0.007   0.2177          
aspect  0.0315  0.3145          
yr  0.0224  0.0484  *       
wk  0.0409  0.0087  **      
month   0.0139  0.5923          
year.jcollect   0.4841  0.0249  *       
wk.yr   0.1002  0.0075  **      
---                 
Signif.codes:0‘***’0.001‘**’0.01‘*’0.05‘.’0.1‘’1            
Permutation: free                   
Number of permutations: 9999                
```


An nMDS and a CCA/RDA serve two different purposes: nMDS is a unconstrained ordination technique, as such, you can't really test the effects of environmental variables on the ordination, you can only do it a posteriori, which is the method implemented in vegan that I believe you used. An unconstrained ordination doesn't serve for testing hypothesis, instead it's only used for dataviz.
On the other hand, a CCA or RDA are constrained ordination techniques that allow you to explicitly include predictor variables on the models and then test their effect. What the hierarchical partitioning does is simply give you the semi-partial R^2 for each variable, which allows you to have a measure of the isolated importance of each variable.
So, if you want to test a hypothesis, I suggest you to go for a constrained ordination, which will also allow you to have more complex designs, such as nested factors or repeated measures.

Thank you! Yes, I did use vegan following my NMDS. I was under the impression that an NMDS was similar to other ordination techniques, only that it does not assume linear relationships. I was anticipating non-linear relationships with many of my variables used to explain variation in the community data. I would like to first identify the variables of importance first in explaining the variation in my community data.
